# Best way to optimize and partition a huge table with 300 million records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I have a table with around 300 million records. As the search is very time consuming I would like to speed up fetching the data.
I have thought of creating partitions on the table. It has indices and a composite key.
I want to know what kind of partitioning will be best suited for the data. Also, the drawbacks of using these partitions.

Comment: To the best of my understanding, there is only one kind of partitioning worth considering at present: range - http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Partitioning does not inherently provide any performance benefit.  What are your slow queries?